# Run ruby script through vba

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to start a Ruby script from through an Excel macro?

The macro creates two CSV files and I would like to automate the procss of running

```
ruby dostuff.rb file1.csv file2.csv
```

Comment: try something like: `Shell("C:\Temp\gc.exe 1", vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: Mmm... I think you can do all from VisualBasic without call a ruby script

Comment: I tried `Shell(" ruby C:\Folder1\dostuff.rb  file1.csv file2.csv" )`

Comment: @Conny are file1 and file2 in the same directory as your excel sheet? Maybe you should fully qualified name

Comment: @Kiril damn you are right, I forgot to add C:\Folder1\ to the files.... Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". When asking you need to show where you've searched and why it didn't help, and preferably what you've tried. We expect evidence of trying to solve the problem yourself. We want to help you, but we don't want to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment section made it clear: fully qualify your parameters, if they are files, and the files are not in the same directory as your Excel sheet.

```
Shell("ruby C:\Folder\dostuff.rb C:\Folder\file1.csv C:\Folder\file2.csv", vbNormalFocus)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to use the environment variable comspec to successfully launch external program from VBA.   [See these blog search result for examples.](https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.co.uk/search?q=comspec)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to run a ruby script with VBA.

With [Shell](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Shell-Function-ff2e4b1b-712d-4e34-aea6-6832eadd3c63), asynchronous with console:

```
Public Sub RunRuby(file As String, ParamArray args())
  Shell "ruby.exe """ & file & """ " & Join(args, " ")
End Sub
```

With [Shell](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Shell-Function-ff2e4b1b-712d-4e34-aea6-6832eadd3c63), synchronous without console:

```
Public Sub RunRuby(file As String, ParamArray args())
  Shell "rubyw.exe """ & file & """ " & Join(args, " ")
End Function
```

With [WScript.Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx), synchronous without console and with exit code:

```
Public Function RunRuby(file As String, ParamArray args()) As Long
  Dim obj As Object
  Set obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  RunRuby = obj.Run("rubyw.exe """ & file & """ " & Join(args, " "), 0, True)
End Function
```

And to set the working directory in case there's a relative path:

```
ChDir "C:\Folder1"
```

, or with the folder of the current workbook:

```
ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
```